# Datetime2 precision in .NET

Tags: visual-studio-2008, sql-server-2008, datetime, precision, datetime2

Microsoft did introduce the Datetime2 type in SQL server 2008.

However, even with VS 2010 (made by the same compagny and realeased 2 years after MSSQL2008), I couldn't find a variable type that would handle Datetime2 with full precision.

Is there any variable type that would allow me to handle Datatime2 in .NET **without any precision lost**?

If the answer is no, do you know if Microsoft have any plan about creating such type in a near future?

Comment: Ahem.... as far as I know, the .NET `DATETIME` structure **always** had that precision - it tooks Microsoft 8 or 9 years after introduction of .NET to have the same thing in SQL Server.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the MSDN Page for [Mapping CLR Parameter Data](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131092.aspx). According to MSDN, your best bet for mapping Datetime2 is using `DateTime` or `Nullable<DateTime>`.

If neither of those meet your requirements, then I'm guessing the answer would be no and I don't think Microsoft would be releasing anything in the near future.

Comment: I think you are right.  I guess my only option would be to create a custom class and use strings to create a SQL statement in order to read / write into the database.